# What am I missing in this recursive function in java

Tags: java, recursion

So I have this homework (I am not trying to cheat) and I posed this question on our class forum, but I am having difficulty understanding the pseudocode that the professor wrote ... how it could possibly work.

The objective is to take a list of strings and "r","w","b" ... 
then reorder them into 6 new strings ...

This is java I wrote based on his pseudocode:

```
public class Solution2 {
    public static ArrayList<String> solve(ArrayList<String> base) {

        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Check for the empty set
        if (base == null) {
            ArrayList<String> empty = new ArrayList<String>();
            return empty;
        }

        char first = 'y';
        String firstString = "";
        for (Iterator<String> i = base.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            if (first == 'y') {
                firstString = i.next();
                base.remove(0);
                first = 'n';
            }

            temp = solve(base);

            for (Iterator<String> n = temp.iterator(); n.hasNext();) {
                // Add first string
                result.add(firstString + n.next());
            }

            return result;
            //

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I just don't know how you keep accumulating the main list of strings. I get an empty set ... which is the base case.

Comment: I know that empty and null are not the same, that Is not what am asking ... I just don't understand how you accumulate the list of string

Comment: it would help if you show what a case with the inputs you use, and what you expect to get.

Comment: it may not be what you're interested in, but when you put errors in your code then that draws people's attention, and makes it harder for you to get relevant answers.

Comment: *"the objective is to take a list of strings and "r","w","b" ... then reorder them into 6 new strings ..."* -  That "objective" does not make sense.  Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: the object is to take r w b, and return rwb, rbc, wrb, wbr, bwr, brw ... I hope that makes sense

Comment: it just seems to me that you are never going to get to the result, because in order for that to happen, you have to pass the result as a parameter, but you are not doing any operation on the result

Comment: Perhaps you could also provide the pseudo code to help better clarify what the code is intended to do?

Comment: The first thing I would do is remove that remove(0) that modifies the input list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should back up and consider a simpler case before you try to make sense of your professor's code, so you know what to look for.

Your recursive function needs a step where it returns a list with the new element added to it and also with the result of the next recursive call.

Say we have a function where we return a list made of the separate characters of a list:

```
static List<String> listChars(String s) {
    if ("".equals(s)) return new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    ret.add(s.substring(0,1));
    ret.addAll(listChars(s.substring(1)));
    return ret; 
}
```

The test harness looks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("result of '' =" + listChars(""));
    System.out.println("result of 'a'=" + listChars("a"));
    System.out.println("result of 'abcd'=" + listChars("abcd"));
}
```

which prints

```
result of '' =[]
result of 'a'=[a]
result of 'abcd'=[a, b, c, d]
```

Your function doesn't have a case like this where you're adding the result of the current iteration plus the results from the next recursive call to the list that you're returning.

Comment: thank you so much Nathan, I had my own solution as well ... but I wanted just one recursive function. I will check this out. thank you so much, so appreciate it